# Home page does not update itself

Tags: feature-request, front-page, live-refresh

I do not get any indication of **"Questions with new activity"** on SO. I have to manually refresh to get new content. I do not face this issue on other Stack Exchange sites. What could be the cause of this anomaly? I tried the Help Center but I was told to ask a question here.

Comment: That's by design. There are so many questions coming in it's be permanently flashing on.

Comment: Aggressive caching (updating it per time interval, instead of when new content arrives) and the fact that the "there are x new questions" bar would otherwise show up all the time.

Comment: [Related post on Meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128882/175248)